# Google Sheets API returns values as strings

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am able to read the range of a given Google Sheet using the NodeJS api, however all the values (even numeric cells) appear as strings. My code is as follows:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

exports.readGoogleSheet = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: '...',
      scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
    });

    const client = await auth.getClient()

    const sheets = google.sheets({
      version: 'v4',
      auth: client
    });


    // read body params
    const docId = req.body.docId; //1uq .....
    const sheetId = req.body.sheetId; //Sheet1
    const range = req.body.range; //A1:C2

    // check if blank
    if (!docId || !sheetId || !range) res.status(400).send('Invalid Parameters')

    const options = {
      spreadsheetId: docId,
      range: `${sheetId}!${_range}`
    };
    
   const {data} = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(options);
   
   console.log(data.values); 
   // this shows something like
   //[ [ 'name', 'value', 'units' ], [ 'Sales', '350000', '$' ] ]
   // notice how the 350000 appears as a string
   // even when it is a plain unformatted number in the google sheet

    res.status(200).send(values);
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err.message);
  }
};
```

Could someone point where I am going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, please include `valueRenderOption` in `options`. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
const options = {
  spreadsheetId: docId,
  range: `${sheetId}!${_range}`
};
```

#### To:

```
const options = {
  spreadsheetId: docId,
  range: `${sheetId}!${_range}`,
  valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",
};
```

- In the current stage, the default value of `valueRenderOption` is `FORMATTED_VALUE`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [ValueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption)

  > `FORMATTED_VALUE`: Values will be calculated & formatted in the reply according to the cell's formatting. Formatting is based on the spreadsheet's locale, not the requesting user's locale. For example, if A1 is 1.23 and A2 is =A1 and formatted as currency, then A2 would return "$1.23".

  > `UNFORMATTED_VALUE`: Values will be calculated, but not formatted in the reply. For example, if A1 is 1.23 and A2 is =A1 and formatted as currency, then A2 would return the number 1.23.

  > `FORMULA`: Values will not be calculated. The reply will include the formulas. For example, if A1 is 1.23 and A2 is =A1 and formatted as currency, then A2 would return "=A1".